# Search for imports which could be TYPE_CHECKING

Tags: python, mypy

I make heavy use of mypy static type checking. I have a large lib where I know I have many imports which are being done just for typehints that could be protected with an `if TYPE_CHECKING` to speed things up.

But searching for them all is proving difficult.

Is there a way to identify these "unused" imports automatically so I can fix them?

Comment: Why? Are these imports the bottleneck of your program? And what happens when those unimported type hints are parsed at function definition time?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/flake8-type-checking/

Comment: @python_user OMG this is exactly it! Thanks so much, my google-fu did not find this. If you want to add an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @JonFitt glad to have helped, left the comment as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`flake8-type-checking`](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-type-checking/) library for this. Installed using `pip install flake8-type-checking`